# Programatically determine if web pages request image (as opposed to simply seeing that there is an img src in the code)

Tags: images

Some of a website's pages have source code that includes `img src="url_to_image"` but the img is not requested by the page. Is there a way to crawl the website to programatically determine if images are in code but not requested?

I'm reasonably familiar with Screaming Frog and Python+Selenium but I don't know if I can make either  do that job.

[edit]

The images are in lazy load code that in turn is inside a div set to display:none. So am I correct in thinking that in those circumstances the browser will not request the images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to do this programmatically rather than as a one-off, one idea would be to load up the page in Selenium and [get a list of all image files that were requested while the page was loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161437/2234742). Then parse the source html of the same page for `img` `src` tags, and compare the list.

The images you're looking for would be part of the second list, but not part of the first.

Comment: Very helpful indeed! Thank you.